# how to navigate to view controller when camera's capture button is pressed

Tags: ios7

After pressing on 'capture image' button in camera screen (with overlay view), it should navigate to next view controller with that captured image. How to achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "overlay view" you mean the UIImagePickerController. You can react to the capture button by implementing methods of the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol. The method you want is imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. In this method you can bring up another view controller, and more importantly dismiss the current image picker.

The class reference explains this process in detail:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html